# How to use CTRL+W instead of CMD+W in Chrome?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome

I'm using my Caps-lock as "CTRL" on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4. On Linux and Windows I can easily close and open tabs via CTRL+W and CTRL+T.

However on Mac I have to use CMD+W and CMD+T. CTRL+W and CTRL+T doesn't work.

What can I to fix this behaviour?

Comment: The easiest fix might just be to remap caps lock to command.

Comment: Whew. Old thread, but nonetheless, quite relevant. How does one remap the keys only in Chrome??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can customize some shortcuts in System Preferences:

[image]

You could also use an application like [Keyboard Mastro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) to assign control-W to a macro that emulates pressing command-W. But it might have a small additional delay or not work everywhere.

But it would be nearly impossible to have the shortcuts changed consistently or to use control instead of command as a modifier key everywhere in OS X.

Comment: You can specify shortcuts ONLY for Chrome also, not just All Applications.

Comment: Note that if you select `Google Chrome` as the application and use the menu item `Close Tab` this actually REPLACES `Cmd+W` so you can't use it to close tabs in Chrome anymore.

Comment: Note also that if you don't want `Ctrl+W` to completely replace `Cmd+W` in Chrome as the above does, you can install the Vimium extension and add `map <c-w> removeTab` to your "custom mappings" in the settings, and then can use EITHER option to close a tab (plus Vimium maps `x` to close a tab too).

You may want to unset most of the defaults if this is the only reason you are using Vimium, but it has some excellent shortcuts well worth exploring. Sadly it can't interact with or close the default New Tab page or chrome:// urls (the former can be changed in the options, see  pages/blank.html).

Comment: It turns out that even if you DON'T select `Google Chrome`, but the generic "App Shortcuts", it will REPLACE `Cmd+W` :/